# Karate mock server - WARN - no scenarios matched, though mock server was started with -m option and mock server feature file

Tags: karate

Trying to replicate a issue using karate mocks and unable to progress getting required response from the mock server initiated. Below is what is done, cant figure out where am I going wrong,

1. Downloaded the jar file under "Assets" sections[hoping this is correct version] from the link https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.2.0
2. mock.feature file is created with below,
   Feature: mock server

   ```
       Scenario: pathMatches('/upload') && methodIs('patch')
       * print 'method:', requestMethod
   ```
3. test.feature file created below for calling mock server endpoint
   Feature: Edit application

Background: Pre-Conditions
* def requestPayload = read('classpath:examples/users/Request.json')
* print requestPayload

Scenario: Test edit application
* url 'http://localhost:8080/upload'
And request requestPayload
And header Content-Type = 'application/json-patch+json'
When method patch
Then status 200

4. Testing this mock server endpoint through POSTMAN and Karate runner class, I notice error below in mock server logs

**WARN com.intuit.karate.core.MockHandler - no scenarios matched, returning 404: PATCH /upload**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have run into this problem: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2028

Solution - use 1.2.1.RC1